# Extract class of each field in data.frame; summarize classes in new data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, summarize

I have a number of very similar .csv's that I want to check through programatically to determine if their column types are the same.

Say I've imported a .csv as a data.frame and I want to check the column classes:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- structure(list(Date = "6/15/2018", Time = structure(44255, class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

test
## A tibble: 1 x 2
#  Date      Time  
#  <chr>     <time>
#1 6/15/2018 12:17
```

Checking the class of each column, I can see that the `Time` column has two classes:

```
map(test, class)
# $`Date`
# [1] "character"

# $Time
# [1] "hms"      "difftime"
```

What I want is a data.frame that ideally would show:

```
Date       Time
character  hms, difftime
```

So that I can easily compare among different csvs.

I thought `map_dfr` or `map_dfc` might work but they return errors.

I also tried the following, but I haven't used summarize_all before and I can't get it to work:

```
test %>% data.frame() %>% 
  summarize_all(funs(paste0(collapse = ", ")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close, you are missing that `funs()` asks you to specify where the column vector is going to go in the function call(s) with `.`. So it would be:

```
test %>%
  summarize_all(funs(paste0(class(.), collapse = ", ")))
```

However, `funs()` is soft-deprecated and throws a warning as of `dplyr` 0.8.0. Instead, you can use the formula notation like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
test <- structure(list(Date = "6/15/2018", Time = structure(44255, class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
test %>%
  summarise_all(~ class(.) %>% str_c(collapse = ", "))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Date      Time         
#>   <chr>     <chr>        
#> 1 character hms, difftime
```

If you want to try using a `purrr` style syntax, here's one way to get it in long format with `imap_dfr` in one line. We write the function to return a named vector for each column, and then bind into a dataframe with `_dfr`. (You could have used `gather` to reshape the wide format version too)

```r
test %>%
  imap_dfr(~ tibble(colname = .y, classes = class(.x) %>% str_c(collapse = ", ")))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   colname classes      
#>   <chr>   <chr>        
#> 1 Date    character    
#> 2 Time    hms, difftime
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `gather`, too - much easier to post-process with a bunch of csvs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
lapply(test, function(x) paste0(class(x), collapse = ', ')) %>% data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks @dww! Accepting the other answer because I'm afraid of `lapply`... haha, I'm a tidyverse convert so taking baby-steps with `purrr`.